# How to capture this pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I have a file in which i need to parse each paragraph. Each paragraph starts with the word "Scenario". I was able to do this using the below pattern

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Scenario(.*?)(?=Scenario)", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
```

Obviously this failed for the last paragraph since there is no look ahead Scenario below.

How do i write a pattern to just capture the last paragraph? I tried writing one where it does negative lookahead on Scenario but that captured all 3 paragraphs. 
Any help on this?

---

```
 Scenario: Blah blah

 Scenario: Blah blah

 Scenario: Blah blah

 Scenario: Blah blah
```

Comment: look for the next scenario or EOF

Comment: but why don't You use lookbehind? like (?<=Scenario).*

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by *paragraph*?  One one or more lines separated from each other by newlines (`\n` or `\r\n`)?

```
(?m)^Scenario:.*(?:[\r\n]+(?!Scenario:).*)*
```

I'm assuming `Scenario:` always appears at the beginning of a line.  Is that what you were trying to do with your negative lookahead?

Or do newlines only occur *between* paragraphs, like in a word processor?  Then you would only need:

```
(?m)^Scenario:.*
```

In either case, you want to use the MULTILINE option (that's what the `(?m)` does), and do **not** use DOTALL.

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification to your regex will work

`Scenario(.*?)(?=Scenario|$)`

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cS2tB7)

CODE:

```
String re = "Scenario(.*?)(?=Scenario|$)";
String str = "Scenario:blah blah
Scenario:blah blah
";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
```